# Searching with control in asp.net using where clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm creating a product search where users can search base of what they want or simply choose `Any` which means it will display `all product`.

since I'm searching based on what is in the `dropdownList` control, if user choose a product `category` i have query the database to display the `product` in that category. How can i query the database to display `product in all category` when the user select '`Any`' from the `dropdownList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you prepare your query include a IF

This is pseudo code, because Im not sure how you store the values in the combo or how you make your sql consult. So is just to give you the general idea.

```
if( dropdwonList.SelectedItem.Value == "any" )  {
    select * from products ;
}
else {
    select * from products where categoryID = dropdwonList.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Or use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE
   ( categoryID = ddCategory.SelectedItem.Value
  OR ddCategory.SelectedItem.Value= -1 // `-1` is your ID for `ANY`
   ) AND
   ( modelID = ddModel.SelectedItem.Value
  OR ddModel.SelectedItem.Value= -1
   ) AND ....
```

Comment: I'm doing the search from visual design not code behind and more also i have about 3 different dropdown user can refine there search with

Comment: Then you should provide that info in your question. Show us some data, some schema to work with. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: there's no reason for not using code behind, since i can do it from visual studio design interface that's why i choose to use design interface

Comment: I include another version for chain multiple filter at once

Comment: You could upvote my question if that help you when you have the privilege